# hiding name@name-macbook-air from iterm2 on mac os x

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, iterm2

As the title of the question says it all. I have `name@name-macbook-air` in my terminal. I would like to hide this. I tried following.

```
export PS1="\W \$" // Does not work even after restarting iterm

// this works but it always put $ but I want full path too but no username and computer name
echo "export PS1='$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile

// This only put '\W' but no directory path
echo "export PS1='\W \$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
```

How can I hide name@name-macbook-air?

**UPDATE**

when I do `echo $PS1` then I get following output

```
%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)
```

I am using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can show `name` instead of `name@name-macbook-air` by putting this line in your `~/.zshrc`: `DEFAULT_USER=name`, where `name == whoami`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove it from the top bar then add this to you `.zshrc` file

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

if you are trying to remove it from the command line interface then you may need to modify the specific theme's `.zsh-theme`. I found this [link](https://gist.github.com/logicmd/4015090#gistcomment-1881695) which may be able to help on that front